# Release Pipeline unpack the zip in linux server

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

i need to unpack the zip file in build agent and then copy to linux server. how can do it.

trigger: none
resources:
pipelines:
- pipeline: MainBuild
source: 'Main - Test and Build'
trigger:
branches:
include:
- fix/SetFTAPipeline
variables:
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0
stages:
- stage: FTA
displayName: FTA_Deploy
variables:
- group: FTA_Variables
pool:
name: 'EX_AgentPools'
demands:
- Agent.Name -equals vmprdbldb999

```
  jobs:
    - deployment: FTA
      environment:
        name:  FTA_AR
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: MainBuild
              artifact: main
            - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
              inputs:
                sshEndpoint: CentOS FTA VM APP1 CBVR 
                sourceFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MainBuild/main/
                contents: '*.zip' 
                targetFolder: /opt/cbvr
                cleanTargetFolder: false 
                overwrite: true 
                failOnEmptySource: false 
                flattenFolders: false
```

Comment: no , the extratfile task didnt work for me. but i am trying to use another SSH task to unzip the file in remote server  - task: SSH@0
              inputs:
                sshEndpoint: 'CentOS FTA VM APP1 CBVR'
                runOptions: 'inline'
                inline: |
                  ssh cbvr@172.22.159.132 'cd opt/cbvr/;unzip -o EQ.MaxitCostBasis.Web.zip -d'
                readyTimeout: '20000'                    but this also not working

Answer (score 0):

> Release Pipeline unpack the zip in linux server

To unpack the zip file in build agent, you could try to use the [Extract Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) task:

```
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    #archiveFilePatterns: '**/*.zip' 
    destinationFolder: 
    #cleanDestinationFolder: true 
    #overwriteExistingFiles: false
    #pathToSevenZipTool:
```

And copy to linux server, uou could try to use [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) task to copy the Artifacts to a Linux Server.

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to copy files from a
> source folder to a target folder on a remote machine over SSH.
>
> This task allows you to connect to a remote machine using SSH and copy
> files matching a set of minimatch patterns from specified source
> folder to target folder on the remote machine. Supported protocols for
> file transfer are SFTP and **SCP** via SFTP. **In addition to Linux**, macOS
> is partially supported.

Please check the developer forum [Copy Files Over SSH during Continuous Integration and Deployment](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/copy-files-over-ssh-during-continuous-integration-and-deployment/) for some more details.